# Why does pecl install a different version for xdebug on another host when using same Dockerfile?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, xdebug

I have a php project. I have setup a dev stack using docker and docker-compose. The php app is using the `php:7.1.2-apache` image as its base.

When running:

```
pecl install xdebug
```

*inside* the container, my container installs:

```
PHP Api Version:         20160303
Zend Module Api No:      20160303
Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
```

Yet now, a colleague builds that container and also exutes that script calling the `pecl install xdebug`, yet for them, it installs a different version:

```
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
```

Why would `pecl install` on the same docker setup install a different version?

(The main difference is the host, mine is an Ubuntu 16.04, my colleague is using a MacOS; yet docker should abstract away the differences.)

What is causing the difference in the php api version?

I want to be able know what actual version gets installed. As this is relevant because for the dev setup, I manually mount a configuration file where I pinpoint to that xdebug file:

```
$ cat docker/php/apache2/20-xdebug.ini 
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.idekey=pstorm
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

And I was not expecting path to change.

```
myapp:
    build: .
    hostname: myapp
    ports:
        - "4430:443"
        - "8080:80"
    command: scripts/start.sh
    volumes:
        - ./docker/php/apache2/20-xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
        - ./:/var/www/myapp
        - ./docker/bashrc:/root/.bashrc
```

My goal is to to always install and load the same xdebug version correctly.

Comment: Could you add a Dockerfile that reproduces it? 20151012 looks more like  php 7.0

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for pointing this out. It was indeed an outdated php7.0 container as my colleague didn't rebuild it but just started the outdated one, expecting it to rebuild automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a docker-compose usage mistake.

My colleague did:

```
$ git pull
$ docker-compose up -d
```

In order to start the container. Since they already built the container in the past, that didn't rebuild the container but reused an outdated one,  based upon `php7.0`.

So they had to run:

```
$ docker-compose up --build
```

to force rebuilding it. Then the setup script worked as expected.